QGIS adding field to multiple layers
is it possible to add a new field to multiple layers (with same geometry)? Layerstyles will only save the style. When I need the same field in all of my point layers, I must do this step by step and add the style.

Try to use the "Add field to attributes table" tool in batch mode

Thanks, I didn´t know this processing tool.
